# Create video file on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, video

Is it possible to create programmatically video file `(e.g. .wmv, .avi, etc.)` (merge `BMP` and `.wav` files) on *Windows Phone*?
I found a lot of 3rd party utilities, but actually they are *C++* based and won't work on *Windows Phone Platform*.

Many thanks,
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you ever found a solution to this? I have tried Splicer to no avail unfortunetaly

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest going this route.. a phone is a light weight device. if you want to do these, would suggest uploading them and doing it elsewhere. once done, the results are downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it was possible I would question its usefulness taking into acount performance of the phones. Encoding video on 1-1.4GHz single core is not really a good idea. You would need either low-level optimizations or hardware encoding, both which are not available to 3rd party developers.

Answer (score 0):

Imaging scenario when you writing RAW video to backend.
1 frame is about 1.5 MB and for several seconds you will get about 100MB to upload.
This couldn't be handled by the mobile data connection (and not mobile as well).
Instead client should pre-process the data and convert RAW video data to compact video files right on the phone (and then submit to server, e.g. for persistent storage).