# Custom VideoSink and CaptureSource frame encoding

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm using CaptureSource to get video stream. In order to save video I can use outof the box FileSink which allows me to save mp4 encoded file but in my application I want to add some adjustments to video stream (add some artifacts, text, logo, etc) and then save it to isolated storage.

I could define derived from VideoSink class and override OnSample method:

```
protected override void OnSample(long sampleTimeInHundredNanoseconds, long frameDurationInHundredNanoseconds, byte[] sampleData)
{
     //process sampleData
     //encode sampleData
     //save encoded sampleData
}
```

But I'm not sure how to encode raw video data on Windows Phone.
I'm looking for any video encoders for WP.

TIA for advice!

Comment: I'm not sure that encoding a video on a phone is a good idea, take a look to this question => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609673/create-video-file-on-windows-phone-7

Comment: If I have camera and Raw video data access I should have option to encode this video for sure. Still looking for approach...